# Complex differential forms over a complexification

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (finite dimensional). Then taking $$TM_{\mathbb{C}}:=TM\otimes\mathbb{C} $$ one can always consider $$\Omega_{\mathbb{R}}(M),\;\;\Omega_{\mathbb{C}}(M),\;\; \Omega_{\mathbb{C}}(M_{\mathbb{C}}), $$ $\mathbb{R}$-valued differential forms over $TM$, $\mathbb{C}$-valued differential forms over $TM$ and $\mathbb{C}$-valued differential forms over $TM_{\mathbb{C}}$, respectively. I would like to know if there is a relation between $\Omega_{\mathbb{C}}(M_{\mathbb{C}})$ and the others algebras.

Comment: What do you mean by “forms over” a vector bundle here? Ordinarily, $\Omega_{\Bbb R}(M)$ would denote real differential forms on $M$.

Comment: Exactly, for example, $\alpha$ $\in$ $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{R}}(M)$ is a map $\alpha:TM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha$ $\in$ $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{C}}(M)$ is a map $\alpha:TM\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha$ $\in$ $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{C}}(M_\mathbb{C})$ is a map $\alpha:TM_{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Comment: What is $M_{\Bbb C}$? If $M$ is real-analytic, then you can complexify, but in general, what do you mean?

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry for my notation, for example, $\alpha$ $\in$ $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{C}}(M_{\mathbb{C}})$ is a map $\alpha:TM_{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Comment: So forget about manifolds. When $V$ is a real vector space, what is the difference between a real linear map $V\to\Bbb C$ and a (real? complex?) linear map $V\otimes C\to\Bbb C$? What kind of map are you talking about, anyhow?

Comment: ohh thank you. I've just realized it!!! it's so trivial!!! jeje thank you